# Organization chart using html and css

Tags: css

In this organization chart, the spacing between the list elements become too large(ex. between name3 and name5, between name5 and name12, between name6 and name11). How can we reduce the spaces between them, so that it can be view in one page without horizontal scrolling. Please help with this

I have attached the code which I tried

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.img-quadrata {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.text-center {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

small {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
}

.tree {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.tree ul {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 60px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 60%;
  height: 15px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*Remove left-right connectors from elements without any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/

ul.first li.first::before,
ul.first li.first::after {
  border: 0 none;
}

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul class="first">
    <li class="first techops">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
        <h3 class="text-center">Name1
          <br/>
          <small> Designation</small></h3>

      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="first techops">

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Name2
              <br/>
              <small> Designation</small></h3>

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Name3
              <br/>
              <small> Designation</small></h3>

          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Name5
              <br/>
              <small> Designation</small></h3>

          </div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                <h3 class="text-center">Name6
                  <br/>
                  <small> Designation</small></h3>

              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Name7
                      <br/>
                      <small> Designation</small></h3>

                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Name8
                      <br/>
                      <small> Designation</small></h3>

                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Name9
                      <br/>
                      <small> Designation</small></h3>

                  </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Name10
                      <br/>
                      <small> Designation</small></h3>

                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
                <h3 class="text-center">Name11
                  <br/>
                  <small> Designation</small></h3>

              </div>
          </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
              <h3 class="text-center">Name12
                <br/>
                <small> Designation</small></h3>

            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
              <h3 class="text-center">Name13
                <br/>
                <small> Designation</small></h3>

            </div>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1417024321782-1375735f8987?q=75&fm=jpg&s=7af3f809a9c1b90b7fcbd71655b661bc" class="img-quadrata center-block">
              <h3 class="text-center">Name14
                <br/>
                <small> Designation</small></h3>

            </div>

          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like your HTML is slightly incorrect.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks for your reply..Can you please tell me what are the mistakes in the HTML

Comment: Try adding `style="position:absolute;left:0px"` to *li* or *ul*-elements and adjust `left` to a proper position.

Comment: @Ann Hey, sorry, I tried to correct them, but still it looks like something is messed up, like a tag mismatch. Give me some time as I am at work, I'll fix them soon.  And provide an answer too.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks for taking time out of your busy schedule